# 98 Toyota Camry won’t crank or start after ignition cylinder replacement

Tags: electrical, toyota, starting, troubleshooting, ignition

Let me start from the beginning my cousins 98 Toyota Camry had a ignition cylinder that wouldn’t turn without hitting it with a hammer. So we went to the salvage yard pulled an ignition cylinder and installed it and it worked great. Except for the fact that when the key was turned to the on position the radio, power plug/lighter, and the power mirrors stop working. They work fine in the ACC position. While trying to diagnose the issue he disconnected the battery after reconnecting the battery when turning the key to start nothing happens. We tried jumping the battery with no effect checked all fuses again and they’re still fine in all locations. I’m about to check the starter but with the other issues I’m not sure that it’s the problem. Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Does the key have a vehicle anti-theft chip in it?

Comment: It doesn’t. There’s no kind of anti-theft or immobilizer.

Comment: The starter is receiving constant power from the battery but the power when you turn the key is not hot at all

Comment: You are talking about the power wire which comes down from the battery is hot all the time (which it should be), but you get nothing out of the energizer wire from the ignition (the wire which fires the solenoid, which engages the starter)?

Comment: OK jumped the starter control wiring it works fine so that should be the culprit does anyone know how to replace that?

Comment: Not sure what you are considering to be the culprit, but jumping across the solenoid would lead me back to somewhere between the ignition switch and the starter solenoid as being the issue. Hopefully that's what you're suggesting.